# How can I add new attributes into my migrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migrate, dbmigrate

I currently have the `migrate` thing like:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :encrypted_password
      t.string :salt

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

now, if I wanna add two new attributes into this file, one is: `t.string :type` , and the other one is: `t.string :memory_token` , how can I do this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already run the migration you will have to create a new one.

`rails g migration AddTypeToUsers`

And then in the migration file you can edit in

```
change_table :users do |t|
  t.string :type
  t.string :memory_token
end
```

Then run a migration `rake db:migrate` to make the changes

If you haven't run the migration then you can simply add

```
  t.string :type
  t.string :memory_token
```

To that file you have showed us and then run your migration

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  The commands I showed you will generate a *brand new* migration file, which is your best option if you have already run `rake db:migrate` on this migration file.  If you haven't run `rake db:migrate` you can simply edit the current migration file and no harm will come.

Comment: Let's simplify this.  Have you run the migration?  you can check by `rake db:migrate:status`

Comment: i did run rake db:migrate already before I posted this question, and can i just simply vim the migrate file to add these new attributes into it?

Comment: No, because you've already run the migration.  Rails remembers the files of migrations it has already ran and will not run them again.  You need to start a new migration.  You can either follow my instructions or @IIya's instructions, both will give you the outcome you want (adding type and memory_token strings to the users table)

Answer (score 2):

+1 to @JTG

You can also make this just with one line:

`rails g migration AddTypeAndMemoryTokenToUsers type:string memory_token:string`

and you will get a following file:

```
class AddTypeAndMemoryTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :type, :string
    add_column :users, :memory_token, :string
  end
end
```

which will make the changes after running `rake db:migrate`